# Sphere Surface Approximation

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

I was wondering why it's possible to approximate the area of a flat circle but not the surface of a sphere by following method.

Equation for semicircle in a $x,y-$system for $y>0$ with $R$ being the Radius: $y = \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$.
I can now define an (non continuous) interval from $-R\le x \le R$ and a step size $dx$  (e.g. $dx=2R/100$) and add up all $y(x)*dx$ pairs. This gives the area of the (half-)circle.

Now I was thinking I could do a similar approach to get the surface area of a sphere $A=4\pi R^2$.
I used the same equation for $y$ as above, just multiplied by $2\pi$. This would give me the circumference of every circle segment with length $dx$. The surface area of such a segment would then be $y*2\pi*dx$. I thought summing up all segments for a large step size should give me the surface area. But it doe snot. There is a rest error of $\sim21$% which won't decrease (max. step size used $500 000$)

Sorry for the bad formation or anything. It's my first post here.
Thanks!

Comment: I presume "step size" means: the number of subdivisions you are using.  In the first case, you are measuring the interior of the circle.  For the  sphere, you are measuring the surface.    So a better starting point would be getting the _circumference_ of a circle down correctly and then expanding to a sphere.  In either case, you have to account for the tilt of the intercepted element.  BTW: this is nibbling at Riemann integration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral     BTW: Try laying out pennies on a sheet of paper, which is what you are doing, there are always percentage gaps.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was indeed subdivisions, I corrected that now. Thanks for your answer. I think I got it :)

Comment: The surface area of each segment is not $2 \pi y dx$. Instead it is $2\pi y dx \sqrt{1+y′^2}$ where y′ is the derivative of y with respect to x.